# Display / Hide Crosstabs by Report Parameters in Birt

Tags: eclipse, birt, crosstab

I have made different crosstabs in a report. I want to display only one crosstab which is selected by report parameter. Others should be hide.

Any solution please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Fanny, but I solved the problem by writing this code in beforeFactory() method.

```
    var oTab = reportContext.getReportRunnable().designHandle.getDesignHandle().findElement("PeriodTab");
    var cTab = reportContext.getReportRunnable().designHandle.getDesignHandle().findElement("WeekTab");
    var pTab = reportContext.getReportRunnable().designHandle.getDesignHandle().findElement("MonthTab");

    if (params["cmbPeriodType"].value == "PeriodTab") {
        oTab.drop();
        pTab.drop();
    }
    else if (params["cmbPeriodType"].value == "WeekTab") {
        pTab.drop();
        cTab.drop();
    }

    else {
        oTab.drop();
        cTab.drop();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should select your cross table
2. in the properties, select 'visibility'
3. check the 'hide element'
4. then go in the expression
5. enter your report parameter. For example, if the report parameter is not 'test' then hide the cross tab. For that you will enter 'parameterName != 'test'' in the function expression.

[image]

Is it clear?